# How to interpret JIRA cumulative Creative vs Resolved graph

Tags: jira

Recently I started to notice that we somehow have resolved more tickets than we've created. Since it seems paradoxical I can only come to two conclusions:

1. There is a bug in JIRA.
2. I don't understand what it is actually graphing.

…or both, I suppose. Here is a screenshot of a graph from this morning:

[image: Created vs Resolved Graph from JIRA]

(The filter that is being graphed is a custom filter. I don't know if that's relevant.)

Is there an explanation for this beyond just "lol JIRA"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This chart shows that your project has

- *71* issues **that are unresolved and have a creation date within the given time period**
- *79* issues **that are resolved and have a resolved date within the given time period**

It tells you that your stock of unresolved Issues has decreased by 8 between 22 Mar and 1 Apr.
Non-cumulative would show you a non-zero value only for the days where at least one issue has been created (red) or resolved (green).

From my point-of-view nothing to worry about. Projects mostly start with more issues created than resolved and work themselves into a good balance. Having resolved more than being created just means you have fixed several open issues and either not found new errors while testing or have not tested at all.

Comment: So in other words we resolved at least eight issues that we created before March 22?

Comment: Yes, at least. You have solved at least 8 issues older than 30 days.